# Перевод double из одной системы счисления в другую

Tags: java, double, системы-счисления

Написал такой код:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int radix = scanner.nextInt();
        String number = scanner.next();
        int radixNew = scanner.nextInt();
        if (radix == radixNew)
            System.out.println(number);
        else if (radix == 1)
            System.out.println(Long.toString((long) Math.ceil(Math.log10(Long.parseLong(number))), radixNew));
        else if (radixNew == 1) {
            for (int i=1; i <= Long.parseLong(number, radix);i++)
                System.out.print(1);
        }
        else
            System.out.println(Long.toString(Long.parseLong(number, radix), radixNew));
    }
}
```

Как можно переделать его на работу с double?(Double.toString и parseDouble работают только с одним параметром и не позволяют переводить числа в другие системы счисления)

Answer (score 2):

Double кодируется по стандарту [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), в котором разделены мантисса, порядок и знак (64 бита).

Есть метод `Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double value)`, который биты IEEE 754 переводит в биты `long`, далее уже эти биты `long` можно переводить в другую систему счисления.